# DWU for Azure SQL DWH

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

I'm trying to provision Azure SQL DWH mostly Gen 2 type, but i'm not sure about the DWU that i need to set.

After analyzing source systems, on an average per day the DWH might be expecting nearly **1.5 million records**. It will be inserted/updated to different set of tables.

With the no. of records is  it possible to ascertain the DWU that needs to be set at DWH level.

Please advice.

Answer (score 1):

While the volume of inserts is a useful number, it is more important to know the volume of data that will be frequently queried. We call this the active data set.

Let's say that you have 10Tb of data. If most of your queries address that whole 10Tb, then your active data set is 10Tb. However, if most of your queries only deal with 10% of your data, your active data set is 1Tb.

Some general guideline examples for DWUc by active data set:

- 1Tb: 500c
- 3Tb: 1000c
- 10Tb: 3000c

That said, in my experience the 1Tb/500c recommendation is a little small. That is because  you're still working on a single node at less than 1000c; and your number of concurrent queries is limited to 20, with 20 concurrency slots. I like to see customers start at 1000c, and only use lesser DWU for dev/test, or during very quiet periods when the DW can't otherwise be paused.